# Virtualenv cannot find my application

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I've been developing an application mainly on my Mac, and now I'm trying to
setup the development environment on a Windows box. The application files are in
place so I started with virtualenv, which installed just fine:

```
<extracted virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz>
cd virtualenv-1.10.1
C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

I navigated to my application dev folder and ran the develop command:

```
(env) C:\Users\eclaird\work\MyApplication>python setup.py develop
```

This seems to run just fine, dependencies installed and all:

```
running develop
running egg_info
writing requirements to MyApplication.egg-info\requires.txt
writing MyApplication.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MyApplication.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MyApplication.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MyApplication.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'rpm\*.json'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'dev_*' found under directory 'MyApplication'
writing manifest file 'MyApplication.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating c:\users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\MyApplication.egg-link (link to .)
Adding MyApplication 1.2.30 to easy-install.pth file
Installing MyApplication-do-stuff.py script to C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\Scripts

Installed c:\users\eclaird\work\MyApplication
Processing dependencies for MyApplication==1.2.30

[... snip ...]

Finished processing dependencies for MyApplication==1.2.30
```

But I get this error when I try to run the application script:

```
(env) C:\Users\eclaird\work\MyApplication>MyApplication-do-stuff.py -c dev-config.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\Scripts\MyApplication-do-stuff.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import require; require('MyApplication==1.2.30')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: MyApplication==1.2.30
```

These same steps have worked fine on my Mac. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that shebangs do nothing on Windows, so running the `MyApplication-do-stuff.py` script was actually handled by the systemwide Python installation. This of course meant you get no packages from the virtual environment, and the obscure error from my question. Running the script like this seems to work:

```
(env) C:\Users\eclaird\work\MyApplication>python ..\env\Scripts\MyApplication-do-stuff.py - -c dev-config.json
```